# Use for loop when writing a XML file with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, linq

I must save data to an XML file, the data is stored in 4 arrays and 2 int. I must use the same element from each array ( Ex `candTur1[0]` with `votTur1[0]`)

I've tried using this code :

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(
   new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
   new XElement("alegeri",
       new XElement("tur",
           new XElement("nrtur", 1),
           for (int i = 0; i < candTur1.Length; i++)
           {
               new XElement("candidat",
               new XElement("nume", candTur1[i]),
               new XElement("voturi",votTur1[i] ),
               new XElement("procent",((votTur1[i] * 100) / votanti)) );
           };
         );
       );
    document.Save("People.xml");
```

All arrays have the same length and the XML should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<alegeri>
  <tur>
    <nrtur>1</nrtur>
    <alegatori>2341</alegatori>
    <candidat>
      <nume>Ion</nume>
      <voturi>50</voturi>
      <procentaj>50</procentaj>
    </candidat>
  </tur>
  <tur>
    <nrtur>2</nrtur>
    <alegatori>2341</alegatori>
    <candidat>
      <nume>Ion</nume>
      <voturi>50</voturi>
      <procentaj>50</procentaj>
    </candidat>
  </tur>
</alegeri>
```

Thanks!

Comment: And whats wrong with your method, what error are you getting?

Comment: How would you like the resulting xml to look like?

Comment: This looks to me like [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) job. Do you mind to use that to *serialize* (write) file? As a bonus you can *deserialize* (read) it back and both operations will takes like 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(
   new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
   new XElement("alegeri",
       Enumerable.Range(1,2).Select(i => 
         new XElement("tur",
           new XElement("nrtur", i),
             candTur1.Select((s, index) =>                
                new XElement("candidat",
                new XElement("nume", candTur1[index]),
                new XElement("voturi",votTur1[index] ),
                new XElement("procent",((votTur1[index] * 100) / votanti)) ))))));
```

I don't know how the arrays looks like, but this code presumes that all arrays are of the same length.

Comment: Yes they are all the same length.

Comment: I've updated my answer to generate the XML you have described.

Comment: Starting with your example I was able to understand the logic and modify the code in order to generate the XML I need.  Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer by @Håkan Fahlstedt an `XElement` can accept an `IEnumerable` of child elements. So as long as you can create a sequence of child elements you can pass that to any element you want.

So to rewrite your example I could first have a method which loops through the arrays:

```
private IEnumerable<XElement> GetArraySequence()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candTur1.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return new XElement("candidat",
            new XElement("nume",candTur1[i]),
            new XElement("voturi",votTur1[i] ),
            new XElement("procent", ((votTur1[i] * 100) / votanti))
        );
    };
}
```

And then you can create your XML document as follows:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("alegeri",
        new XElement("tur",
            new XElement("nrtur", 1)),
            GetArraySequence()
    ));
```