# adding item index in xml with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this code:

```
private XElement buildTemplateOrderXML(List<TemplateOrderLines> templateOrderLines, String sessionId, XNamespace ns1)
    {
        //build the xml objects and return them
        return new XElement(ns1 + "TemplateParameters",
            templateOrderLines.Select(item =>
                new XElement(ns1 + "TemplateOrderLines",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "TemplatePartDesc", item.TemplatePartDesc),
                    new XElement(ns1 + "TemplatePartSKU", item.TemplatePartSKU),
                    new XElement(ns1 + "TemplateQuantity", item.TemplateQuantity)
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

This produces an XML like this.

```
<ns1:TemplateParameters>
  <ns1:TemplateOrderLines>
    <ns1:TemplatePartDesc/>
    <ns1:TemplatePartSKU>NSD-CH02</ns1:TemplatePartSKU>
    <ns1:TemplateQuantity>2</ns1:TemplateQuantity>
  </ns1:TemplateOrderLines>
  <ns1:TemplateOrderLines>
    <ns1:TemplatePartDesc/>
    <ns1:TemplatePartSKU>NSD-TK02</ns1:TemplatePartSKU>
    <ns1:TemplateQuantity>1</ns1:TemplateQuantity>
  </ns1:TemplateOrderLines>
</ns1:TemplateParameters>
```

What i want is this:

```
<TemplateParameters>
      <TemplateOrderLines>
        <item0>
          <TemplatePartDesc/>
          <TemplatePartSKU>NSC-CH02</TemplatePartSKU>
          <TemplateQuantity>5</TemplateQuantity>
        </item0>
        <item1>
          <TemplatePartDesc/>
          <TemplatePartSKU>NSC-TK02</TemplatePartSKU>
          <TemplateQuantity>5</TemplateQuantity>
        </item1>
      </TemplateOrderLines>
    </TemplateParameters>
```

How do i modify my code to generate the `<item0>` `<item1>` part?

P.S. I am aware of the `<ns1:TemplateOrderLines>` repeating. I know how to fix that so i am not worried about that bit now.

This is a similar question [Use for loop when writing a XML file with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432243/use-for-loop-when-writing-a-xml-file-with-linq)

Comment: Any efforts from your end so far?

Comment: I google searched but did not find the answer. I think i am not using the right searches. If you have ideas on what i should search for that would help as well.

Comment: Xml of this kind: `item{N}` - hard to parse and process. Don't use it! In the extreme case, add the `Id` or `Index` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`.Select` has an overload which accepts a `Func` that takes the index within the current enumerable, so you could write this:

```
return new XElement(ns1 + "TemplateParameters",
    new XElement(ns1 + "TemplateOrderLines",
        templateOrderLines.Select((item, index) => 
            new XElement($"Item{index}",
                new XElement(ns1 + "TemplatePartDesc", item.TemplatePartDesc),
                new XElement(ns1 + "TemplatePartSKU", item.TemplatePartSKU),
                new XElement(ns1 + "TemplateQuantity", item.TemplateQuantity)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

But note that -- as @AlexanderPetrov notes in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690915/adding-item-index-in-xml-with-linq/51691295#comment90348146_51690915) -- that XML written like this is very hard to parse; it's hard to find multiple tags that start with the same string (in this case `Item`). If you really must, add the index as an attribute.

Keep in mind, however, that when parsing the XML using LINQ, you can use the same overload to get an index over the enumerable, so you may not need to embed the index in the data at all.